# Detecting user<->kernel transitions with hypervisor

Tags: debugging, debuggers, kernel-mode, kernel, intel

Is it possible to use a hypervisor to trap all ring0<->ring3 transitions (both 0->3 and 3->0)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. I do not want to go into details as there are a lot of comprehensive material available online:

- [Intels manuals](http://www.read.seas.harvard.edu/~kohler/class/aosref/IA32-3.pdf) which you will have to study in any case if you really want to understand how things work (from personal experience)
- [A VMM-based System Call Interposition Framework for Program Monitoring](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2cd9/bfcc8d8bd7703f265a7a3e7da2167dfb39ff.pdf) - one of the countless examples about sys call monitoring mainly for security purposes.
- [HyperPlatform](https://github.com/tandasat/HyperPlatform) - Intel VT-x based hypervisor aiming to provide a thin VM-exit filtering platform on Windows.

  - [DdiMon](https://github.com/tandasat/DdiMon) - Monitoring and controlling kernel API calls with stealth hook using EPT

One of the techniques is to monitor execution of the kernel-mode entering code pointed by `IA32_SYSENTER_EIP`/`IA32_LSTAR`.